# Play 2 as backend-only API

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created a couple large backend APIs with Play 1.2. Now that I have created some free time for myself, I'm interested in trying to do the same with Play 2. However, it seems all the [tutorials](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ScalaTodoList) and [sample projects](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Samples) only give use cases for dealing with form data.

When I say backend-only APIs, I'm referring to something that does not render any views that are readable to humans. More specifically, for example, a backend service to a mobile application. Most of its responses will be formatted as JSON data.

I know that the documentation shows how to parse a JSON request, but it still seems as though that is meant to be an exception. I realize I could be totally mistaken, but I just find it strange that all of Play's examples seem to use form data for interacting with controllers as opposed to external calls doing so.

Is Play 2 still the right choice for this use case? If so, are there any good sample projects or tutorials for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Play for Scala](http://www.manning.com/hilton/) has an entire chapter (Chapter 8) dedicated to this topic (in the context of building a single-page web application). Whether a technology is "right" for a particular need is a matter of judgment, but there is no question Play supports the REST API use case.

Play has sophisticated mechanisms for reading, validating, and writing JSON (with all kinds of custom formatting capability). You also have the typical Play benefits of asynchronous reactive programming to enable scaling to a large number of clients

The only real tricky thing is how you handle authentication if that matters.

Comment: For authentication I'd suggest the HMAC as known ie. from Microsoft's Azure or Amazon's AWS

Answer (score 0):

[Play for Java](http://www.manning.com/leroux/) chapter 6 gives directions to JSON usage.

JSON usage should be pretty easy and pluggable. Jackson or GSON, your choice, with body parser you'll get JSON presentation and can return JSON stream directly. Logic is up to you.

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
  public static Result index() {
  RequestBody body = request().body();
 return ok("We expected to get json: " + body.asJson());
}
```

Using body parsers is easy, so also java works here fine, but Scala seems to have really neat features that give you some JSON superpowers if you are up to it.

As a sidenote: I personally have tried to find way to use at backend API's HTTP+XML+Smooks Transformations+JPA, and results are as notes [here](http://nikkijuk.blogspot.de/2013/08/simple-xml-to-jpa-data-service-with.html).